# SSIS package to read multiple files and load into multiple tables based on file name

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am very new to SSIS and I have a requirement where I receive multiple text files each day to a folder location and I need to load each file to a different table, each file has a different file format that matches its corresponding target table. For ex: File1 has 5 fields, so Table1 also has exact same 5 fields. File2 has 8 fields, Table2 also has exact same 8 fields.

All files are received in the same folder location. File name pattern is Table1.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.txt (first file)

```
Table2.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.txt         (`second file`)  

Table3.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.txt         (`third file`)

Table4.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.txt          (`fourth file`)
```

My target table names are as follows: Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4

I need to load 'Table1.YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.txt' into 'Table1' and similarly other files into their respective tables. After loading each file, I need to move the file to a different folder. I want to know if a for loop solution will solve this? If so how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I would have 4 - foreach containers each with a dataflow and a file system task.

set the folder appropriately and your file name contains the mask that you want.

i.e table1*.txt

[image]